Unable to browse mail subfolders on iOS clients with specific server. Dovecot and Maildir
This is a bit of an odd one, and I'd appreciate any advice. If this is better for ServerFault instead, let me know.
I don't think this belongs in AskDifferent or similar. While I am talking about a behaviour I am seeing on my iOS devices regarding mail, I believe it to be an issue on the server-side because for 2 main reasons:

The behaviour only started after updates to the server
The behaviour is only in accounts for this server, a second mail server I set up in the same way does not have this issue on the same iOS devices

The issue
About a month ago, I updated my mail server from Debian 11 to 12. Everything seemed to go off without a hitch, no errors in the syslog, can send and receive emails from my usual client software, so all good.
Over the following days, I found I could not move emails into subfolders on my iPhone or iPad. I can select the email(s) I want to move, then select the folder I want to move them to, and they disappear from the list and immediately return.
This does not effect deleting emails (as in, sending them to Trash), or moving mail between the Inbox and Junk folders.
I also found if I browse to a mail folder, "top-level" folders are fine, but any folders inside them cause an "Account Error" message, directing me to settings to check the account password.
Inbox <–– Accessible
Financial <–– Accessible
Financial/Receipts <–– Inaccessible on iOS clients

When I perform any of these actions with my mail.log file being tail'd it just looks normal. For browsing a folder: Connection established for my user, then log out with "no commands sent" noted. For moving a email: Connection established for my user occurs twice, and nothing else.
None of this is a problem on my Mac, however, where I can still browse those folders, move messages to and from them, everything, no issue.
My IMAP Prefix is the same on all three devices (blank).
On Dovecot, my mailbox_location is set as "maildir:~/Maildir:LAYOUT=fs".
I'm hoping someone here will have run into something like this before. That, or can point me to where I might get more information from my server or clients that can help me find a cause.
Thanks for reading!
Edit 1 (2nd April):
The IMAP List command produces all my mail folders as I would expect to see them, e.g:
2 list "" "*"
* LIST (\HasChildren) "/" Financial
* LIST (\HasChildren) "/" Financial/Receipts
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Financial/Receipts/eBay Receipts"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren \Sent) "/" Sent
* LIST (\HasNoChildren \Drafts) "/" Drafts
* LIST (\HasNoChildren \Trash) "/" Trash
* LIST (\HasNoChildren \Junk) "/" Junk
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" INBOX
...

Likewise, lsub didn't look unusual to me...
3 lsub "" "*"
* LSUB (\Junk) "/" Junk
* LSUB (\Trash) "/" Trash
* LSUB (\Drafts) "/" Drafts
* LSUB (\Sent) "/" Sent
* LSUB () "/" Financial
* LSUB () "/" Financial/Receipts
* LSUB () "/" "Financial/Receipts/eBay Receipts"
...

Sorry I forgot to mention, I do have the separator set to "/", which namespace confirms:
4 namespace
* NAMESPACE (("" "/")) NIL NIL

Edit 2 (3rd April):
I have also now found that my second mail server, which I updated the same way at the same time, does not have this issue on any of my devices. I'll dump the config files tonight from both servers for comparison and hopefully that will explain the behaviour
Edit 3 (3rd April):
New twist. I installed the Developer "Mail" and "Sync" logging profiles to my phone to see what IMAP commands and responses were happening in Mail on my iPhone, and found that the phone was trying to SELECT the folders without separators (so for example 15 SELECT "FinancialReceipts" instead of 15 SELECT "Financial/Receipts"). Weirdly however, every other command would use the separator (like STATUS).
I added the rawlog config to Dovecot's 10-master.conf file and ran doveadm reload to enable logging of the IMAP session for my account.
The first pair of .in and .out files now showed the SELECT commands being sent with the correct separator. I testing browsing a few folders on the phone and they synced fine, and I could move messages to subfolders as well.
I deleted the rawlog configuration and reloaded Dovecot again, and initially moving messages and browsing subfolders was working, but now about half an hour later, it has stopped again.
Given I had restarted Dovecot to try and resolve this before and it made no difference, I don't think running doveadm reload was what made things work again. I'm thinking that it has to do with a change of state in Dovecot when I enabled rawlogging...

Purely out of curiosity, what does the IMAP 'LIST' response look like – do the subfolders show up, what separator is used? (Connect to localhost:143, do a login "User" "password", then b list "" "*" and c lsub "" "*", and maybe d namespace to find out what separator the IMAP server advertises.) I wonder if the problem might be LAYOUT=FS (I'm using the traditional Courier layout and have no problems with ancient iOS).

Does this issue occur in clients running on non-iOS devices?

@u1686_grawity, I've added an edit section on my question with the output of all of those. I've been using LAYOUT=FS since I put this server up in the first place and not had issues before so hopefully not that

@music2myear, I have the account signed in to my mail app on OS X and do not have this issue, which is from a different "generation" of Apple software than my iOS devices. I can spin up a Ubuntu VM tomorrow night when I have more time and see if Thunderbird works fine or also has the issue if you think that will help troubleshooting

The problem is, then, that this question is about a mobile device, because desktop/pc clients are not having the same issue. You could delete this question here and ask it on Ask Different, out iOS/Mac sister site, but it is off topic here.

@music2myear: I asked it here as while the behaviour is surfaced on the mobile device, it occurred as a result of changes on the server end (or at least correlating with those changes). I had initially thought to post in ServerFault, however past posts there about my dovecot/postfix setup have been rejected because I'm not using them in a business environment, and back then they sent me here.

I have also now found that my second mail server, which I updated the same way at the same time, does not have this issue on any of my devices. I'll dump the config files tonight from both servers for comparison and hopefully that will explain the behaviour

I see. Perhaps, if you get any more Close Votes, you may find it helpful to add a sentence clarifying that to the question, just below the paragraph about you observing this behavior on the iPhone. Something like "While this behavior is only happening on iOS, it occurred due to changes made on the server, and so this question is about the server side."

I did kind of say that in one of the last paragraphs of the question. Not about iOS, but about believing the problem to be server side due to that having the most recent changes.
I'll move that to the top of the question and reword it though, to make it clearer. Thanks for the feedback :-)
